# How to get the variable value in Laravel 7 export?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export

I am trying to get the $status value in the Status column, so How will i get this using the below code

```
public function collection() {

    if(Auth::user()->is_accepted == 1) {
        $status = 'Accepted';
    } elseif (Auth::user()->is_accepted == NULL) {
        $status = 'Waiting Confirmation';
    } else {
        $status = 'Rejected';
    }

    return Entrepreneur::select('name', 'contact', 'address', 'business_name', 'business_contact', 'business_address', 'is_accepted')->get();
}

public function headings(): array {
    return [
        'Name',
        'Contact',
        'Address',
        'Business Name',
        'Business Contact',
        'Business address',
        'Status'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `map()` function  ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map
by this u can add new key to any collection

```php
public function collection()
    {
        $entrepreneur =  Entrepreneur::select('name', 'contact', 'address', 'business_name', 'business_contact', 'business_address')->get();
        $entrepreneur->map(function ($row) {
            if ($row['is_accepted'] == 1) {
                $status = 'Accepted';
            } elseif ($row['is_accepted'] == NULL) {
                $status = 'Waiting Confirmation';
            } else {
                $status = 'Rejected';
            }
            return $status;
        });
        return $entrepreneur;
    }
```

Comment: it is taking all as NULL value and prints Waiting Confirmation

Comment: no please check $status what u r getting then.? your $status value should be correct as your question was how to put a variable this is your solution rest u have to manage your code :D

Comment: it is taking all the values NULL

Answer (score -1):

u can try using Eloquent Mutators , se reference : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Enterpreneur extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'your_table';
  protected $appends = ['status']; //edit forgot to add this one
  //assumed all column except primary fillable
  protected $fillable ['name', 'contact', 'address', 'business_name', 'business_contact', 'business_address', 'is_accepted'];
  
  public function getStatusAttribute()
  {
    if($this->is_accepted == 1) {
      return 'Accepted';
    } elseif ($this->is_accepted == NULL) {
      return 'Waiting Confirmation';
    } else {
      return 'Rejected';
    }
  }
}
```

then `Enterpreneur::select('columns')->get(); //modified 'status will be added'`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.